# JavaScript Null value error

Tags: javascript, null

I've created this simple application with Javascript however I keep getting an error that says "`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null`" and this happens on the line "`var age = document.getElementById("age").value;`" I keep looking every where for the issue but I just dont see it. Please review my code and help me out. Thanks!

```
<script>
        function calculateBMR()
    {
        var gender = document.getElementById("gender").value;
        var age = document.getElementById("age").value;
        var weigth = document.getElementById("weight").value;
        var heigth = document.getElementById("height").value;
        console.log(gender);
        if (gender == "male")
        {
            var result = 66 + ( 6.23 * weight) + ( 12.7 * height ) - ( 6.8 *age );

        }
        else if (gender == "female")
        {
            var result = 655 + ( 4.35 * weight ) + ( 4.7 * height ) - ( 4.7 * age );
        }
        document.bmrForm.bmr.value = result;
    };
    </script>
    <form name = "bmrForm">
        Gender:
            <br />
        <select id="gender">
        <option value="male">male</option>
        <option value="female">female</option>
        </select>
            <br />
        Age:
            <br />
        <input type = "text" name ="age" size = "10">
            <br />
        Weigth (lb.) :
            <br />
        <input type = "text" name ="weight" size = "10">
            <br />
        Heigth (inches) :
            <br />
        <input type = "text" name = "height" size = "10">
            <br />
            <br />
        <input type = "button" value = "Calculate BMR" onClick = "calculateBMR();">
            <br />
            <br />
          BMR:
            <br />
        <input type = "text" name = "bmr">
    </form>
```

Comment: ID's not found on page `age`, `weight`, `height`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were looking for elements whose ID is `age`, `height` and `weight`, while there are no HTML elements with these IDs.

Try using them like this:

```
<input type = "text" name ="age" size = "10" id="age">
<input type = "text" name ="weight" size = "10" id="weight">
<input type = "text" name ="height" size = "10" id="height">
```

**Edit:**
You should not use `document.getElementById(...).value` directly, as it *could* be undefined, depending on the HTML it's used on. Also, if the user inputs a non-numeric value, you are guaranteed to have some kind of invalid result (exception, miscalculations, etc).

You should therefore change your JavaScript accordingly:

```
var ageElement = document.getElementById('age');

if (ageElement != undefined)
    age = Number(ageElement.value);

if (Number.isNaN(age))
    // Do your calculations.
```

Comment: I'm confused why this would be the accepted answer, since it fails to identify the misspellings ("height" vs. "heigth"), which would cause the program to not work, and also does not point out that you can not do numerical arithmetic directly with the result of `.value` (because it is a string).

Comment: @torazaburo Thanks for correcting my answer. However, Mike is only using `*` on strings, which is fine, as long as user input is a valid number.
I will edit my answer accordingly